# IE flickering input in jQuery overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, internet-explorer

I'm utilizing the jQuery UI Library to create an overlay.

For simplicities sake, they live on the page (not being pulled in via an AJAX call) and are initialized via an onclick.

When they are shown, in IE 6 and 7, when you click inside any text inputs (input type text or textarea) the cursor flickers sporadically.

Of note also, when I hover over the overlay using the developer toolbar, the "blue border" flickers like mad as well.

I'm figuring this is a redraw issue (due to the flickering) but I cannot figure out for the life of me *why* it's a redraw issue (unless the jQuery UI library is giving faulty math, as this is my next step, I'm hoping SO can cut down on my debugging and tell me I'm an idiot or say I'm on the right track).

Comment: Can you please provide the javascript code that is initializing the overlay?

Answer (score 0):

Needs more specifics but perhaps try changing your css so that the element has `cursor: text;` ..http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_cursor.asp